# Adding a Facebook feed to website causes problems

Tags: facebook, feed

Does anyone know why when you add a Facebook feed to your website, in Firefox the closing head and opening body tags show up in red? Is there a way to combat this as W3 schools reckons that the website is not up to standard. Example [click here](http://www.thewritedesign.co.uk/dtpt)

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any code to display. It's on the view source on the website

Comment: I did click the link, in Firefox even.  I can't see any red tags.  I looked in the Firefox document inspector, but everything looked fine.

Comment: @Wizard:  The idea is you should create a minimal reproduction with a small amount of code.  Then you can include that code in your question.

Comment: @Wizard If you can't reproduce your problems in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), at least take a screenshot showing what you're seeing.

Comment: I can't work out how to show you what I'm seeing. There doesn't appear to be anyway I can attach an image

Comment: You may not yet have sufficient reputation to attach an image, but you've got to give us some way of reproducing what you're seeing.  A sequence of steps; what to click on; something.

Comment: Ah, I know. Facebook tells you to add this code to your header. <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: then tells you to add then tells you to add <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/DannyTymonPtAndBootCampMuayThai?ref=profile" data-width="625" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div> where you want the feed to appear. Firefox then makes the closing head and opening body tag in red ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `div` is inside the head element.  `<div id="fb-root"></div>` and the following code needs to appear somewhere after the `<body>` tag.

What's currently happening is your browser sees the `<div>` tag which can not appear inside `<head>`, so it implicitly closes the head and opens the body.  Then, when your `</head>` tag appears, the browser rightfully complains about a duplicate closing tag.

To fix it, you need to put that code inside the `<body>` where it belongs.